# NSString writeToFile, NSSavePanel and write permissions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've only been leaning Cocoa/Objective C for a few days so apologies that this is probably simple/obvious but it's got me stumped.

I've written this handler for saving 3 floats to a text file. However when I'm running it the files are not being saved. Could anyone suggest if there's an error in my code or if you think there's something else (like file write permissions) preventing the file from being written.

Research has lead me to look into Sandboxing, but that gets confusing very quickly and I'm hoping just running the app from xcode in debug would let me write to my user directory.

Heres the code:

```
- (IBAction)saveResultsAction:(id)sender {

    //Sets up the data to save
    NSString *saveLens = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Screen width is %.02f \n Screen Height is %.02f \n Lens is %.02f:1",
        self.myLens.screenWidth,
        self.myLens.screenHeight,
        self.myLens.lensRatio];

    NSSavePanel *save = [NSSavePanel savePanel];

    long int result = [save runModal];

    if (result == NSOKButton) {
        NSURL *selectedFile = [save URL];
        NSLog(@"Save URL is %@", selectedFile);
        NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@.txt", selectedFile];
        NSLog(@"Appended URL is %@", fileName);
        [saveLens writeToFile:fileName
                   atomically:YES
                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                        error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nsurl  is no nsstring. You could use the selectedFile.path property

Comment: You are appending the file extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a NSURL object is no POSIX path..

its a URL and getting its description doesnt make it a path

---

`NSString *fileName = [selectedFile.path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"txt"];`

---

BUT as said, you shouldnt have to append the .txt at all. just use what the panel returns. Else, there would be sandboxd errors because you dont have access rights to the modified filename :)

`NSString *fileName = selectedFile.path;`

Comment: Thanks for your responses. NSString *fileName = selectedFile.path writes the files as desired, but without the extention. using stringByAppendingPathExtension writes the files with the desired extension.

Comment: @RichPorter: Probably because, if the code in your question is accurate, you haven't set the save panel's allowed file types.

Comment: Better yet, use `writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:`. You don't need to extract a path for this.

Comment: @Peter Hosey Thanks, I'd scrapped my original block and started again shortly before I posted here. Restoring a `setAllowedFileTypes` got me back to where i wanted to be without using `stringByAppendingPathExtension`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't need to append the file extension to the URL.The extension is already there.You could directly do this:

```
if (result == NSOKButton)
{   
    [saveLens writeToURL: [save URL]
                atomically:YES
                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                     error:nil];
}
```

Comment: the url returns a description in the file:// scheme, no? (if not ill rewoke my voting of course).

Comment: I assumed the extension at first too but worst case, there'd be files like foo.txt.txt or a visible sandbox error

Comment: Well I haven't tested with a path like the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've already accepted an answer, but it may also be helpful to know how to debug this type of issue using `NSError` pointers.

Cocoa uses `NSError` with method calls which generate error conditions, which richly encapsulate errors. (Objective-C also has exceptions, but they're reserved for cases of programmer error, like an array index out of bounds, or a nil parameter that should never be.)

When you have a method which accepts an error pointer, usually it also return a `BOOL` indicating overall success or failure. Here's how to get more information:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![saveLens writeToFile:fileName
                atomically:YES
                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                     error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
```

Or even:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![saveLens writeToFile:fileName
                atomically:YES
                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                     error:&error]) {
    [NSApp presentError:error];
}
```

Comment: Thats great I've not experimented with NSError yet. Ill give it a try thanks.